# Avoid model validation of relations classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I had View strongly type of my class `Usario` Defined like this

```
public partial class Usuario
{
    public Usuario()
    {
        this.Campana = new HashSet<Campana>();
    }

    public int IDUsuario { get; set; }
    public int IDPerfil_FK { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Activo { get; set; }

    public virtual Perfil Perfil { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Campana> Campana { get; set; }
}
```

Now what i want to know is how can I avoid the validations of the class campana which is related with the class Usuario in the view, because when I doing `ModelState.IsValid` the Model validates the attributes of the class Usuario and also of class the Campana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is to use view models.

You already have `Usuario` class, now you implement the view model, which will only hold the properties you want to pass to the view. Something like:

```
public class UsuarioProfileViewModel
{
    public int IDUsuario { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public bool Activo { get; set; }

    // Other properties for that view
}
```

Now on the controller:

```
public ActionResult UsuarioProfile(UsuarioProfileViewModel model) {
{
    // Fill the missing properties for the model (when needed)

    View(model);
}
```

This way you only pass to the view the needed data. Data annotations work for view models exactly the same way as any other class.

`model` is initialized by MVC and properties are filled in with incoming data, through routeValues, so you can do something like this:

```
@Html.Action("UsuarioProfile", new { UsuarioID = 10 })
```